# Manual function to sort 3 numbers, lowest to highest

Tags: python

So for my homework problem, I have to use 3 functions to create a manual version of the sort() function: moreThan(), swap(), and sort3(). sort3() is obviously the function that calls the other two. My problem is that the swap function isn't being called correctly inside sort3(), and never actually executes.

I've been trying to mess around with changing the values in the swap() function, trying to list swap()'s return values in tuples and lists, and none of those things worked.

```
def moreThan(moreOne, moreTwo):
    if moreOne > moreTwo:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def swap(swapOne, swapTwo):
    swapOne, swapTwo = swapTwo, swapOne
    return (swapOne, swapTwo)

def sort3(sortOne, sortTwo, sortThree):
    if moreThan(sortOne, sortTwo) == True:
        swap(sortOne, sortTwo)
        print("swap one worked")
    if moreThan(sortOne, sortThree) == True:
        swap(sortOne, sortThree)
        print("swap two worked")
    if moreThan(sortTwo, sortThree) == True:
        swap(sortTwo, sortThree)
        print("swap three worked")
    print(sortOne, sortTwo, sortThree)
sort3(1,3,2)
```

The expected output is 1,2,3. However, the actual output is 1,3,2, as if the values aren't getting swapped at all.

Comment: On top of the answers here, I'll just note that you've made this a little over complicated w.r.t. the parts other than `swap`. You don't need `moreThan`, and you don't need `== True`: https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/35844a7727d13c0c733ff033f4822eb5

Comment: you aren't doing anything with the return value of `swap`, so I'm not sure what you expect to happen. python does not support call by reference semantics

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't allow a function to rebind local variables in the caller's namespace. This means your swap() call doesn't really do anything. You'd want to call the function this way:

```
sortOne, sortThree = swap(sortOne, sortThree)
```

but in this case, turning this into a function doesn't really help with readability or reusability, so you might as well just inline the function.

Alternatively, if you can change your function signatures and you keep your unsorted data on a mutable data structure like list, you might want to pass that, so swap becomes `swap(list, index1, index2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set sortOne, sortTwo, and sortThree equal to the outputs of your swap function:

```
def moreThan(moreOne, moreTwo):
    if moreOne > moreTwo:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def swap(swapOne, swapTwo):
    swapOne, swapTwo = swapTwo, swapOne
    return (swapOne, swapTwo)

def sort3(sortOne, sortTwo, sortThree):
    if moreThan(sortOne, sortTwo) == True:
        sortTwo, sortTwo = swap(sortOne, sortTwo)
        print("swap one worked")
    if moreThan(sortOne, sortThree) == True:
        sortOne, sortThree = swap(sortOne, sortThree)
        print("swap two worked")
    if moreThan(sortTwo, sortThree) == True:
        sortTwo, sortThree = swap(sortTwo, sortThree)
        print("swap three worked")
    print(sortOne, sortTwo, sortThree)
sort3(1,3,2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your output is equal to your input because you are not performing these operations in place. When you pass these values as arguments to your `swap` method, `swap` creates its own copies of the values in its own variable, thus the values of your inputs `sortOne` `sortTwo` and `sortThree` are never being changed. You would want to change your `sort3` function like this:

```
def sort3(sortOne, sortTwo, sortThree):
if moreThan(sortOne, sortTwo) == True:
    sortOne,sortTwo = swap(sortOne, sortTwo)
    print("swap one worked")
if moreThan(sortOne, sortThree) == True:
    sortOne,sortThree = swap(sortOne, sortThree)
    print("swap two worked")
if moreThan(sortTwo, sortThree) == True:
    sortTwo,sortThree = swap(sortTwo, sortThree)
    print("swap three worked")
print(sortOne, sortTwo, sortThree)
```

as this will update the values of `sortOne` `sortTwo` and `sortThree`.

Comment: although you are correct that the OP needs to capture the returned values, passing arguments **never copies** python does not use call by value.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree with you about Python not using call by value. Saying 'copies' is ambiguous here but call by value is not what I was suggesting. Ints are immutable types in Python, so is it not true that Python uses (when I meant by copies) the value of `swapOne` and `swapTwo` when in the `swap` method, as it is not assigning anything to the passed references, but taking their values and using them in the operation?

Comment: well, simply put, you don't mutate either of the objects, thus no effects will be seen in the caller.